# How to listen to long click on a navigationview item?

Tags: android, navigationview

I'm developing an android app using design library and appCompat library. I'm facing some issues when tried to listen to long click on a menu item.
My app has a NavigationView as a side menu, inside this navigationview I had a menu with a lot of items. 
I can listen to click of these items but I can't listen to the long click.
Does anybody know how do I implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**update**

You can use:

```
Menu myMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem myItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.my_item);

myItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
       // do something 

    }
});
```

Comment: This will set onLongclickListener on my NavigationView, but I must implement it on a navigation view item.

Comment: @AndersonNunesdaSilva please take a look at my code now and see if it helps.

Comment: For me the `setOnLongClickListener(...)` method doesn't exist. Any solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/q/37899080/4583267

Comment: @ThomasVos look to my answer at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, but you have to set the popup_layout.xml into the **MENU** folder and write in the tags `<menu>` and not constraint layout or something like that.

in my Java class I wrote this for my list and important write R.menu.yourlayout):

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(ViewListContents.this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = p.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_layout, p.getMenu());
        p.show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you have any questions ask me in the comments.